# Is it true that $q\nmid k$ where $q$ is the characteristic of a ring and $k$ is the order of any unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $(R,+,\times)$ be a finite ring with an identity. (Dis)Prove that $q\nmid
>  k$ where $q=\text{Char}(R)$ is the characteristic of a ring and $k=\text{Ord}(r)$ is
>   the order of a unit $r$.

If $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then $q=n$ and $k\mid \varphi(n)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler function. It holds.

If $R=\mathbb{F}_{p^s}$, then $q=p$ and $k\mid p^s-1$ where $p$ is prime. It holds.

If $R=GR(p^s,r)$, then $q=p^s$ and $k\mid (p^r-1)p^{(s-1)}$, where $p$ is prime. It holds.

I am wondering if it holds for all rings.

Comment: It holds for integral domains or any ring of prime characteristic without nilpotent element : if $u^p = 1$ then $(u-1)^p=0$ which implies $u=1$.

Comment: @reuns it seems that these conditions are sufficient but not necessary. Can you verify whether the two examples given by Ben meet these conditions? I think $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p)$ does. How about the other example?

Comment: @reuns Does $p$-nilpotent just mean $x^p=0$ (not also $x^q\neq 0$ for $q<p$)? Else in $F_3[x]/(x^2)$, $1+x$ is a unit of order 3.

Comment: Right it doesn't work because there are things like $R=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-1) \times \Bbb{F}_2$ where $(x ,1)$ is of order $2$ in $R^\times$ but it is of order $1$ in $R/(2)^\times$ @Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can take products of two rings whose unit groups orders divide each others characteristic.

- Take $F_4$ has units $C_3$ and $F_3$ has units $C_2$, so $F_4\times F_3$ which has characteristic 6 has units $C_3\times C_2$.

ADDED:

Another thing you can do is take nilpotent extensions to add more units to a given ring, of orders divisible by the characteristic. For example

- $F_{p}[x]/(x^p)$, which has a unit $1+x$ of order $p$.
- Hochschild square-zero extension of $R$ by a module $I$ with some element of order divisible by the characteristic of $R$. These extensions have isomorphic copy of $I$ in their unit group as $1+I \subset R^\times\times I$.

ADDED LATER:

For finite commutative rings, being *reduced* is equivalent to *semisimple* (cf. [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical); [Semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module)), in other words a product of finite fields (by Artin-Wedderburn), like in our first example.

Comment: Is it possible to characterize those rings in which the orders of unit groups divide the characteristic ?

Comment: @zongxiangyi I doubt anyone has tried to do this. I added an example of indecomposable rings just to show they exist. There is no classification of finite rings to build off of, so it sounds hard.

Comment: I do not think that $F_{p}[x]/(x^p)$ is not indecomposable ring and it has $$\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/(x^p)\cong \mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{F}_p.$$. How do you define "a ring is indecomposable" ?

Comment: @zongxiangyi That is an isomorphism of vector spaces but not of rings. By indecomposable I mean its not isomorphic (in the category of rings) to a nontrivial product of two rings. This is equivalent to existence of nontrivial idempotents. For instance if $p=2$ none of $0,1,x,1+x$ are idempotent so its not a product of rings.

Comment: These rings are local so they are indecomposable/have no nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: Would you give me some references introducing "indecomposable ring" ? I can not find this concept on several textbooks.

Comment: It's just an ad hoc terminology for "ring that is not a product of two nontrivial rings."

Comment: There is something similar for groups (https://www.planetmath.org/indecomposablegroup), and you can look up the notion of indecomposable module (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_module). A ring $R$ is "indecomposable" iff its (right) regular module is an indecomposable $R$-module. This is because $R = End(R_R)$, and if $R$ has a nontrivial idempotent $e \in R$ then $R \cong Re \times R(1-e)$.